# Still get "invalid_client" on vimeo api athough I got "code"

Tags: c#, wpf, vimeo-api

I got code but run this below code that show "invalid_client". I test on Spotify ok.

```json
{
  "error":"invalid_client",
  "error_description":"A valid client ID must be provided along with any request made to Vimeo's API"
}
```

```cs
var SpotifyUrl = "https://api.vimeo.com/oauth/authorize?client_id=" + Uri.EscapeDataString("7......e96c30f") + " &response_type=code&redirect_uri=" + Uri.EscapeDataString("http://localhost:8888/callback") + "&state=xyzbc&show_dialog=true";
            var StartUri = new Uri(SpotifyUrl);
            var EndUri = new Uri("http://localhost:8888/callback");

var postData = new List<KeyValuePair<String, String>>();
            postData.Add(new KeyValuePair<String, String>("grant_type", "authorization_code"));
            postData.Add(new KeyValuePair<String, String>("code", code));
            postData.Add(new KeyValuePair<String, String>("redirect_uri", Uri.EscapeDataString("http://localhost:8888/callback")));
            postData.Add(new KeyValuePair<String, String>("client_id", clientid));     
            HttpContent content = new FormUrlEncodedContent(postData);
            String response = "";
            try
            {
                var data = await client.PostAsync("https://api.vimeo.com/oauth/access_token", content);
                byte[] result =  data.Content.ReadAsByteArrayAsync().Result;
                response = Encoding.UTF8.GetString(result, 0, result.Length);
            }
```

Comment: "The provided redirect uri does not match the one used to create the authorization code".

Answer (score 1):

I'm fairly certain your issue is the trailing space you're adding to your `client_id`...

(Scroll right, I've indicated the spot)

```
var SpotifyUrl = "https://api.vimeo.com/oauth/authorize?client_id=" + Uri.EscapeDataString("7......e96c30f") + " &response_type=code&redirect_uri=" + Uri.EscapeDataString("http://localhost:8888/callback") + "&state=xyzbc&show_dialog=true";
----------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------^
```

This will be appending a %20 (space) to the end of the client_id

Comment: sorry, i'm still not successful.

Comment: I still got a code and state. the problem is in here var data = await client.PostAsync("https://api.vimeo.com/oauth/access_token", content);
                byte[] result =  data.Content.ReadAsByteArrayAsync().Result;
                response = Encoding.UTF8.GetString(result, 0, result.Length);

Comment: @michealbarrons Well, that's just the point where the actual request is fired off to the server and we wait for a response. Any problems with the request will appear on that line. I'd also point out that a callback url of "localhost" may not work, depending on how it's being used (I'm unfamiliar with the Vimeo API). If it's used by your machine, that's fine but if it's used server-side, spotify will interpret localhost as meaning the serer it runs on. That said, I focused on the client_id as that's where the error says the problem is.

Comment: Another thought: You're sending the client_id twice, once in the URL and once in the body. Depending on what happens server-side, it may be treating it as a list with 2 entries (both your client_id). Try removing it from the body and/or url and see if that helps